# Java - Can you assign methods to an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a beginner to programming as a whole and I was wondering instead of typing what's given below, if there's a way you can assign these variable names into a String[] or making it to where I'm not typing the same code over and over again just with different variables?

```
  JButton one = new JButton("1");
  one.addActionListener(new Numbers());
  add(one);

  JButton two = new JButton("2");
  two.addActionListener(new Numbers());
  add(two);

  JButton three = new JButton("3");
  three.addActionListener(new Numbers());
  add(three);
```

Thanks!

Comment: The first one is different than the two others - has `panel4.add()` instead of  just `add`. Is that intentional? Because you won't be able to generalize if it is.

Comment: You would create a method for this kind of job. And pass in the number to the method as a parameter.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, well not just with the `String` but you could use more complex structure with the component to add into.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but you could assign your `JButtons` to an array.

```
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[3];
for(int i = 0;i < 3; i++) {
    buttons[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
    buttons[i].addActionListener(new Numbers());
    add(buttons[i]);
}
```

if you don't need to access the jbutton references later on, you don't even need the array.

```
for(int i = 0;i < 3; i++) {
    JButton jb = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
    jb.addActionListener(new Numbers());
    add(jb);
}
```